# Unable to set outputCacheSettings in WebConfig file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, output-caching

I am Trying to implement outputcaching in my website When I try to add

```
    <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
        <add name="TwoDay" duration="43200" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
</outputCacheSettings>
```

This to my webconfig file it throws an error

```
    The configuration section 'outputCacheSettings' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
```

I have added above code inside

```
<configuration>
```

section in webconfig.
Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it in the `<caching>` section in the `<system.web>` section as explained [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: That changed the error ..thats it..
 The configuration section 'caching' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: Excuse me, `<caching>` is a child of `<system.web>`.

Comment: easy to make a mistake and put to <system.webServer> what creates this error